# fullcalendar - Switch axis on weekly view

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

We are using fullcalendar plugin on our Angular.js application.
Is there a way/ documentation to customized the Weekly view and switch between the day and time columns ? I've searched for a solution and could not found one. Your help is much appreciated!

[image: fullcalendar default]

[image: custom view]

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is not a simple way to do this. In theory you could write a totally custom view as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js, but this is quite a big job, so consider if it's really 100% necessary to display the calendar like this, or whether the existing layout will in fact be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson Will try this method.

Comment: Ok well good luck, I would suspect that even if you clone an existing view, it may be several weeks of work if you are not familiar with the fullCalendar source code.